# clip-path rendering bug in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, clip-path

I have run in to a rendering issue in Chrome.
Im building a site where all the content is in a fixed position, stacked upon eachother and is revealed by scrolling via clip-path.

This has been working perfectly until a few days ago when the site started having rendering issues in chrome. It works great i Edge  and Mozilla.

I have striped down the code to the bare minimum as seen below.

```css
.parent {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.child__title {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 8vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.green {
  background-color: #E6F0E0;
}

.blue {
  background-color: #E0E2F0;
}

.red {
  background-color: #F0E0E0;
}
```

```html
<section class="parent red">
  <div class="child">
    <h2 class="child__title">The first slide</h2>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="parent blue">
  <div class="child">
    <h2 class="child__title">Another Slide</h2>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="parent green">
  <div class="child">
    <h2 class="child__title">The last slide</h2>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: latest Chrome with windows seems to work fine.

Comment: Strange, I tried it on 3 diffrent computers, lates chrome and windows. Same bug on all of them.

Comment: Worth noting is that the content renders fine in the code snippet but when run locally or on website I experience the bug again.

Comment: Then you have to chase what disturbs it. Edit your style sheets and remove all style but the one you have here on the snippet and add your styles by chunks untill it goes wrong (you might do hat from the develloper tools of your browser. Unless it is something about the markup.